# Prevent users from deleting EGDB tables

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-dbms, delete

Oracle 18c/10.7.1 geodatabase:

My geodatabase has an owner/schema/user called OPERATIONS.

Operations staff have a direct db connection in ArcMap/Catalog to the OPERATIONS owner. This connection is needed so that staff can create and alter tables in OPERATIONS.

I want to prevent Operations staff from deleting tables in the OPERATIONS owner.

What are my options for doing this?

Comment: Fire them if they delete tables? If you grant someone the access to CREATE and ALTER tables, that also gives them the right to DROP as well. If you don't trust your operations staff to do the right thing, then they shouldn't have the password to that login. While I won't say I've never altered a table, I will say that it doesn't and shouldn't happen often. Infrequent enough that a batch script can run with the necessary permission.

Comment: I think the question is not about GIS but about Oracle and might belong better to db admin site. Perhap a trigger like here https://community.oracle.com/thread/961302 could help.

Answer (score 1):

Creating Oracle Trigger would help
https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=prevent-drop-table